# Динамическая смена иконок в зависимости от темы приложения Android

Tags: android, themes, android-themes

Приложение может быть активно в двух цветовых решениях :

- светлом
- темном

В приложении используются темы:

- Для светлой я использую: Theme.AppCompat.Light
- Для темной:  Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Возможно ли как-нибудь загрузить пак иконок в приложение(светлых и темных), чтобы они подтягивались в зависимости от темы приложения?

Comment: Вот вроде по твоей теме [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267852/android-how-to-obtain-the-resource-id-of-the-current-theme) и [2](https://gist.github.com/laaptu/9628e40024b5a020f066)